# Java Android - .equals not working

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, equals

I am trying to set the selected spinner item in view mode but .equals method is returning false every time even though both strings are equal.

I tried :

> spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).getItemAtPosition(i).equals(myString)
>
> spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equalsIgnoreCase(myString)
>
> spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(myString)
>
> spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(myString)
>
> spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(myString.trim())
>
> spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(myString.toString().trim())

In all cases it's returning false only.. Where did I go wrong?

This is the code to set the selected item to spinner:

```
my_spinner.setSelection(getSpinnerIndex(my_spinner, "myString"));
```

This is my get Spinner Index Method:

```
private int getSpinnerIndex(Spinner spinner, String myString) {
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++) {
            if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(myString.trim())) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
```

When I inspect the line:

> spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().trim()

Result is = myString

When I inspect the line:

> myString

Result is =  myString

but this line:

> if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(myString.toString().trim())) {

Returning false??

EDIT:

this is my String Array:

```
String[] allStrings = {"myString", "string", "myNewString"};
```

My Adapter code:

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private List<MyDomain> myList = new ArrayList<>();

        MyAdapter(List<MyDomain> myList) {
            NeedRepairActivity.this.myList = myList;
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater.from(NeedRepairActivity.this));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return myList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public MyDomain getItem(int position) {
            return myList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return getCount();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            if (view == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.each_item, null);

                // getting all view here

                
            }

            return view;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            ImageView myImage;
            TextView myComment;
            TextView myAmount;
            TextView myName;
            TextView myChoice;
           
        }
    }
```

Here I am trying to show the selected item in custom dialog like:

```
// on click on list item
        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
                MyDomain domain = (MyDomain) myListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                dialog = new MyCustomDialog(MyActivity.this, domain);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Here is my Custom Dialog class to show selected spinner item in view mode:

```
public class MyCustomDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

        Context context;
        MyDomain MyDomain1 = null;

        public MyCustomDialog(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public MyCustomDialog(Context context, MyDomain myDomain) {
            super(context);
            this.context = context;
            this.myDomain1 = myDomain;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

            
            ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<>(MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, allStrings);
            adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mySpinner.setAdapter(adp);

            // set selected items if comes from edit mode
            if (myDomain1 != null) {

                
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(myDomain1.subType)) {

                    mySpinner.setSelection(getSpinnerIndex(mySpinner, MyDomain1.subType));
                    subCatName = MyDomain1.subType;
                    setSpinnerText(mySpinner, myDomain1.subType); // assume this is "myString"  here
                }

            }
            
        }

       /* private void setSpinnerText(final Spinner spin, String selectedText) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < spin.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                    if (spin.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString().equals(selectedText)) { // here getting selectedText as myString and spin.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString() as myString but //returning false
                        spin.setSelection(i);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                
            }
        }*/

        private int getSpinnerIndex(Spinner spinner, String myString) {
            int index = 0;

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++) {
                    String spinnerItem = spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                    if (spinnerItem.equalsIgnoreCase(myString)) { // here getting myString as "myString" and spin.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString() as "myString" but returning false
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                
            }
            return index;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the contents of `myString` ? And why do you use `myString.toString()` ?

Comment: Why you are not use actual List or Array to compare value instead of getting value from spinner item?

Comment: I just tried with myString only still same issue @Fildor

Comment: Did you try to use *contains* instead?

Comment: No I can't If I use contains it may have duplicate items in my array. So did't used it @DEADMC

Comment: @ShylendraMadda I think spinner.getItemAtPosition(i) is provide view reference instead of value.

Comment: Its good to have an arraylist corresponding to spinner values. Now just get the index of selected item. Get the corresponding value from array list. Compare this with the target string value with .equalsIgnoreCase

Comment: @HareshChhelana Nope when I inspect it returning exactly same string value no?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda can you add the Adapter and list/array used for spinner also

Comment: Sure Sanjeet just a min

Comment: What SpinnerAdapter are you using? It's probably better to get the index from there.

Comment: @ShylendraMadda I think here myString.toString().trim() you don't required toString() because myString is already String variable.

Comment: yes true I agree , but  if I remove it also same result no? See I already added all tried cases
 @HareshChhelana

Comment: Try getting the spinner value in a string before comparing it in `if` statement, then compare this string with my string. also log the string and see

Comment: @Redman Okay I am going to try and let you know

Comment: try to Clean and Rebuild your project once

Comment: @Redman No same result :(

Comment: what did you get in  log  of spinner string?

Comment: @Akshay I tried that too In this case some strings are getting true result as well.. In some scenario it's getting false even though there was same strings

Comment: @Redman here in this case --> myString as I mentioned in the question

Comment: Please show us getItem() of your adapter

Comment: Is there any need to clear the cache something like here?

Comment: what its `myString` and still getting false?  it like you are comparing `if(10==10)` and getting `false` as result

Comment: No I am passing "myString" to getSpinnerIndex to get the position where it is matching in the array.. i.e., I am trying to compare like `if(myString.equals("myString"))` It returning false..

Comment: please post you class file code..

Comment: @ShylendraMadda please also add Adapter code (if using custom adapter add class file of the adapter)

Comment: Just check this way   `String str=spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()`  Log this `str` value and also Log `myString` value.  now check condition `if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(myString))` . also check both strings in Log if both strings str and myString  are same in log and your if condition is still giving false ,then some thing is wrong with your android studio

Comment: @Redman Haha.. I too in the same situation it's giving same result while inspecting but returning false a result.. It's very rare case to say why happening like this..

Comment: @ShylendraMadda You are using a list of **MyDomain** in adapter but while comparing you are using Strings. Are you sure you are using the same String array **(allStrings )** as in question for adapter??

Comment: @ShylendraMadda as a last thing try doing File-->Invalidate caches/restart...

Comment: @Sanjeet Yes sanjeet I am using same String for here just posted my adapter by editing little bit, it's giving same result while inspecting but returning false a result, I need answer for this. there is no problem with strings

Comment: @ShylendraMadda I'm confused now a little. I think the issue is with data types. Can you add the code snippet where are you initializing the adapter and setting it to spinner. And don't edit anything.

Comment: @Sanjeet was asking for same :P

Comment: Finally fixed without changing anything in my code just rebuild and clean the project as Akshay said. Thanks to every one for you support..thanks Akshay

Comment: Always welcome :)

Comment: But still in some cases getting first value as a result in spinner but selected is different in list. If I checked if condition still both strings are same why happening I didn't get.. it's very horrible..